# MIN( ) with conditions? MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with a few columns and I'm doing a `GROUP BY`.  In addition to getting other columns I want to get the `MIN()` value of one column when the other column is `NULL`.  Here's what I have so far:

Table columns:

```
id        INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
table2_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
iteration INT(11) UNSIGNED,
timestamp INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    table2_id,
    COUNT(id) as total,
    COUNT(iteration) as completed,

    # I want the MIN(timestamp) but only when
    # iteration IS NULL
    MIN(timestamp) as next_incomplete
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    table2_id
```

Comment: You shouldn't be selecting `id` if it's not in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Good point! Post edited

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this for the `MIN` expression:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN iteration IS NULL THEN timestamp END) as next_incomplete
```